# CSS Border shifts text down when I start animation

Tags: html, css

On a website I was making, I was trying to create a border animation that flashed yellow and purple repeatedly around an image. I came out with this:

```
@-webkit-keyframes battle {
    0% {
    border:5px solid yellow;
    -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
    -moz-border-radius: 25px;
    padding: 0px;
    }
    50% {
    border:5px solid purple;
    -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
    -moz-border-radius: 25px;
    padding: 0px;
    }
}
```

I activated it with a :hover element. However, when I hovered my mouse over it, the border appeared and repeatedly pushed the text below up and down. I tried to add a border to the animated element but the animated border just went on top of the border.

Is there a way to fix this? Any help would be great.

Comment: First of all, what's `battle`? Is it a class or an ID?

Comment: You could add a transparent border when it's not hovered. this way, the size won't change.

Comment: @clabe45 Its the name of the animation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the basic border in the class of the element that you are going to animate, then let the animation deal only with the change of the border color.

```css
.animated {
  border: 5px solid transparent; /** the basic border **/
  border-radius: 25px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

.animated:hover {
  animation: battle 1s infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes battle {
    from {
      border-color: yellow;
    }

    to {
      border-color: purple;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="animated">
  This is the content
</div>
```